# Adding an onclick event to google.map marker

Tags: javascript, api, google-maps

I'm stuck trying to figure out a little bit of JS :( I have a google map

```
var myCenter=new google.maps.LatLng(53, -1.33);

function initialize()
{
var mapProp = {
    center:myCenter,
    zoom: 14,
    draggable: false,
    scrollwheel: false,
    mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
};

var map=new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"),mapProp);

var marker=new google.maps.Marker({
    position:myCenter,
    icon:'images/pin.png',
    url: 'http://www.google.com/',
    animation:google.maps.Animation.DROP
});
marker.setMap(map);
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

But I can't seem to hook up the onclick event for the marker url?

I know it has something to do with adding

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {window.location.href = marker.url;});
```

But where ever I put it causes the map to not display or the marker to not display.

Comment: Wheres your infoWindow?

Comment: @Alex I don't need an infoWindow. I'm talking about adding a URL click event to the marker (pin). Thanks though. I think Skelly has the answer.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Make sure the `marker` is defined outside of initialize(). Otherwise, it will be `undefined` if you attempt to assign the click listener outside of initialize().

Also, you may have SAME-ORIGIN issues if you attempt to load url `www.google.com`, but it should work fine with a local url.

**Updated code**

```
var myCenter=new google.maps.LatLng(53, -1.33);

var marker=new google.maps.Marker({
    position:myCenter,
    url: '/',
    animation:google.maps.Animation.DROP
});

function initialize()
{
var mapProp = {
    center:myCenter,
    zoom: 14,
    draggable: false,
    scrollwheel: false,
    mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
};

var map=new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"),mapProp);

marker.setMap(map);
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {window.location.href = marker.url;});
```

[**Working Demo on Bootply**](http://bootply.com/63491)

Comment: What if I create markers dynamically via (mapClick) event and want to define 'click' hander for the each inside?

Answer (score 7):

This is what I’d use:

```
var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(53, -1.33);

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), {
    center: latLng,
    draggable: false,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    scrollwheel: false,
    zoom: 14
});

var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
    icon: 'images/pin.png',
    map: map,
    position: latLng
});

google.maps.event.addDomListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    window.location.href = 'http://www.google.co.uk/';
});
```

I’m not sure if you can store a `url` property with a `Marker` object.

If you need to display multiple markers (i.e. from an API call) then you can use a `for` loop like this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
    (function(marker) {
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
            icon: 'images/pin.png',
            map: map,
            position: market.latLng
        });

        google.maps.event.addDomListener(marker, 'click', function() {
            window.location.href = marker.url;
        });
    })(markers[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<div id="googleMap" style="width:60%;height:300px;" onclick="placeMarker();"></div>
<script>
    function myMap() {
        var mapProp= {
        center:new google.maps.LatLng(15.28983, 73.95482),
        zoom:5,
        };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"),mapProp);
        google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) {
        placeMarker(map, event.latLng);
        });
    }
        function placeMarker(map, location) {
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: location,
            map: map
        });         
        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content: 'Latitude: ' + location.lat() +
            '<br>Longitude: ' + location.lng()
            
        });
        infowindow.open(map,marker);
        document.getElementById("sitelatitude").value = location.lat();
        document.getElementById("sitelongitude").value = location.lng();
        }
</script>

<script async defer
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API&callback=myMap">
</script>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I've done in the past.  The only difference I see between my code and yours is that I set the marker map in the marker options, and you're setting in with marker.setMap(Map);

```
var marker = new window.google.maps.Marker({
        position: markerPosition,
        map: map,
        draggable: false,
        zIndex: zIndex,
        icon: getNewIcon(markerType != "archive", isBig)
        , animation: markerAnimation
    });


    window.google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
        // do stuff
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure where your content is but you would need to do the following...

```
var yourContent = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: 'blah blah'
});

google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
  yourContent.open(map,marker);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-25.363882, 131.044922);
var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 4,
    center: myLatlng,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
};
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: myLatlng,
    map: map,
    title: 'Hello World!',
    url: 'http://www.google.com'
});
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
    window.location = marker.url;
});
```

If you go to this page: https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/full/marker-simple

and paste the code above into the console you will see that it works.

I think the problem you have is the following, you need to put this line:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
    window.location = marker.url;
});
```

inside of your initialize function.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I have multiple markers and I wanted to know which marker was clicked. I found following solution on google forum - https://groups.google.com/g/google-maps-js-api-v3/c/cAJrWZWdD-8?pli=1

By Chris Broadfoot (Google Employee)

> You can reference the clicked marker with 'this':
>
> google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', markerListener);
>
> function markerListener() {   alert(this.getPosition());   //
> this.setIcon(... }