# Google maps, addlistener not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am using Google Maps in a project and I want to display some clickable markers on the map, each one of them is showing a Div with diffrent data, so this I started my code by getting the data form the database and works well, then i display it on map like this:

```
    showHazardsOnMap(result);

    function showHazardsOnMap(hazards) {
    var imgHzr = {
        url: "images/hazardPointer.png", // url
        scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(60, 60), // scaled size
        origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0), // origin
        anchor: new google.maps.Point(0, 0)
    };

    setMapOnAll(null);
    for (var i = 0; i < hazards.length; i++) {
        markerHzr = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: { lat: hazards[i].Hazard_Lat, lng: hazards[i].Hazard_Long     },
            map: map,
            icon: imgHzr,
            animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP
        });
        showHazardDetails(marker, hazards[i]);
        }
        }
    }

    function showHazardDetails(mark, data) {
        google.maps.event.addListener(mark, 'click', function () {  
            alert("clicked!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!");
            $("#hazardID").html(data.Hazard_ID);
            $("#hazardImgInfo").attr("src", data.Hazard_Image);
            $("#pDate").html(data.Hazard_DateTime);
            $("#pDes").html(data.Hazard_Description);
            $(".hazardInfo").fadeIn(1000);
        });
    }
```

Ok, now I can see the markers on the map, when I click a marker somtimes the alert("click!!!") work but it's not showing my the Div that I want to see, and sometimes its not showing me even the alert.

I'll attach the part of HTML,CSS maybe they'll help

```
.hazardInfo {
width: 80%;
height: 80%;
background-color: #f5821f;
z-index: 2000;
position: fixed;
top: 10%;
right: 10%;
opacity:0.9;
text-align: center;
display: none;
border: none;
border-radius: 10px;    
}


<div class="hazardInfo">
    <p id="hazardID"></p>
    <img src="images/backbtn.png" class="backButton" /><br>
    <p id="pDate" style="font-size:18px; margin-top:11%;"></p><br>
    <img src="images/156.jpg" id="hazardImgInfo" style="height: 40%; width: 90%; border-radius:15px;"><br>
    <p id="pDes" style="font-size:17px; margin-top:4%; margin-right:4%; width:90%;"></p><br>
    <div id="thumbsUp">הוסף לרשימה</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding an onclick event to google.map marker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16985867/adding-an-onclick-event-to-google-map-marker)

Comment: I get a javascript error with the posted code: `Uncaught ReferenceError: marker is not defined`.  You have a typo in the posted code: `showHazardDetails(marker, hazards[i]);`  If I fix that (change it to `markerHzr`, it works for me (at least does what I expect)).

Comment: markerHzr is an image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code crash because when the listener is calling, the value of `mark` and `infowindow` have already changed. You can try something like this (just change the `showHazardDetails` function):

```
function showHazardDetails(mark, data) {
    google.maps.event.addListener(mark, 'click', function () {  
        alert("clicked!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!");
        console.log (mark);
        console.log (data);
    });
}
```

Normally, the output will be always the same for `mark` and `data`.

In order to pass the real value of the marker, contentString and infowindow, you have to create an [IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Glossaire/IIFE). Like this, the value of the variables will be copy inside the function:

```
function showHazardDetails(mark, data) {
    (function (zmark, zdata) {
    google.maps.event.addListener(zmark, 'click', function () {  
        alert("clicked!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!");
        $("#hazardID").html(zdata.Hazard_ID);
        $("#hazardImgInfo").attr("src", zdata.Hazard_Image);
        $("#pDate").html(zdata.Hazard_DateTime);
        $("#pDes").html(zdata.Hazard_Description);
        $(".hazardInfo").fadeIn(1000);
    });
    })(mark, data);
}
```

You may look [how closures work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work).

*Tell me if you have some questions.*

Comment: Nice one brother <3 work 100% 
I'll read also the links you attached